# SQL - Keep one value in a column and assign the rest as Zero

Tags: sql-server

This is my first time asking a question in this forum. I am new to SQL and this website has helped me a lot in the past and has become a number one source of information when it comes to SQL questions. I am very thankful for that.

I have a table that looks like this

```
CompanyNo | BatchNo| Location | Batch_Count
--------------------------------------------------
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31     
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31    
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31    
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31    
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31
```

I want to keep the `Batch_Count` for one record only and assign the rest as Zero

Like this..

```
CompanyNo | BatchNo| Location | Batch_Count
--------------------------------------------------
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   31  
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   0    
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   0  
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   0  
01        |  102    |   NJ     |   0
```

I tried using `Row_NUM`, `RANK`, and `Dense_Rank` functions, but wasn't able to achieve that outcome. Maybe I am not doing it right?

Can anyone help me out or point me to the right direction to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the query you are using currently for which you are not getting the desired result.

Comment: Also, you would be more on-topic in dba.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: Where is the primary key in the table? All rows are equals, which is the point?

Comment: Are you trying to update the data in the table, or just select the desired results?   And yes, please post your attempt to solve this so we can debug it.

Comment: This looks more likely as client-side issue.

Comment: I am using HaloSource to build a cube. I am trying to build a fact table in SSMS. Because my company uses Halo instead of Microsoft BI Stack or other BIDS, the primary keys and indexes are not present in my databases. Halo automatically drops and re-creates tables when the project is deployed/processed. I am not sure if I explained it clearly. Bottom line is, my database do not have primary keys and indexes and we use concatenation of multiple columns like companyno, productid, and warehouses to implement joins.  Thank you all for your replies. The issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CompanyNo,BatchNo,Location,CASE Batch1_Count WHEN 1 THEN Batch_Count
ELSE 0 END AS Batch_Count
FROM 
(
  SELECT CompanyNo,BatchNo,Location,Batch_Count,
  ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY Batch_Count ORDER BY Batch_Count DESC) 
  AS Batch1_Count FROM Table1
) 
AS Test
```

Comment: You do not have to club the query inside. U can directly use like below - SELECT CompanyNo,BatchNo,Location
,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyNo,BatchNo,[Location] ORDER BY Batch_Count DESC) = 1 
  THEN Batch_Count ELSE 0 END Batch_Count
FROM Table1

Comment: @JayShankarGupta - your partition by clause is not correct i think. We should use Id columns for partition by.

Comment: yeah i know for better clarity i did that. Yeah i think partition is on id is right thanks for suggestion